# Entity Framework data access

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently working on a team project where we have to work with the Entity Framework.
Our WinForms application is using the `MVC` design pattern, and by that fact, we are not quite sure how to work with the data.

1. Would it be best just to work with the `context` and make changes to this?
2. Or, would it be best to create a `DataManager` class that is part of
   the `Controller`, and then create the appropriate (needed) methods
   within this class? For example, if we need a method that returns all
   persons with IDs between x and y, then we would make this method in
   the DataManager that takes x and y as input.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like [repository pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx). There are a lot more less formal samples with code on the web. One of "bonus"  advantages is that you can make a fake implementation that does not go to DB and use it for unit testing.

But there is no one best approach to this problem.

Comment: Agreed, I'd use the repository pattern as well. You can find an example for EF framework here: [Implementing ISession in EF4](http://geeksharp.com/2010/11/16/implementing-isession-in-ef4/)

Comment: I also like this. EF's automatic change tracking and things is nice if you manipulate the proxies directly, but the repository pattern gives you so much freedom for testing and, particularly in my usage, the ability to give all your database access to another thread.

Comment: Nice. It definitely looks interesting. Then the implementation is just another matter. Also, the ISession interface could be the way to go. Thanks!